# Convert Object.entries reduce to Generics type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function in TypeScript, what it does is convert an enum to an array.

```js
function toKeyValList(e: any) {
  return Object.entries(e).reduce((acc: any, val: any[]) => {
    acc.push({ key: val[0], value: val[1] });
    return acc;
  }, []);
}
```

```js
enum IncidentRecordStatus {
  IN_PROCESS = 'IN_PROCESS',
  CLOSE = 'CLOSE',
}

const list = toKeyValList(IncidentRecordStatus);

[LOG]: [{
  "key": "IN_PROCESS",
  "value": "IN_PROCESS"
}, {
  "key": "CLOSE",
  "value": "CLOSE"
}]
```

I would like to convert it to a generic function without using the "any" type

I tried this way, but I get an error

```js
export function toKeyValList<T>(e: T): T {
  return (Object.entries(e) as Array<[keyof T, T[keyof T]]>).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
    acc.push({ key: key, value: value });
    return acc;
  }, e as T);
}
```

what would be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to infer return type, try to avoid mutations in TypeScript.
Consider this example:

```js
const toKeyValList = <
  Obj extends Record<string, string>
>(obj: Obj) =>
  Object
    .entries(obj)
    .reduce<{ key: string, value: string }[]>(
      (acc, [key, value]) => [...acc, { key, value }],
      []
    );

enum IncidentRecordStatus {
  IN_PROCESS = 'IN_PROCESS',
  CLOSE = 'CLOSE',
}

// {
//     key: string;
//     value: string;
// }[]
const list = toKeyValList(IncidentRecordStatus);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAjGHsDsGcBcAJbgNIFMCeA1AhgGwDICWc8AvPADzDzwDyARgFbyoAesqkAJtPAEqoIAJy4U4QwpADmAGnjjJUgHzAlACnBMAXHSYBKMipoNGg2NRrwAdJ1gTU0Dfos0rQ1FwCuoVBQDe8ADWGDoK0nIAbnieqKF2ivAAvgDaALrqLpZq2KCgcsnB6JHRqKkGpErwyVY1OXnwAYXFuDFJqTKZNGmZegDcIJyeALbwAJKQoIRctgLCXADKsNiwnrx%20FqMAcgD6AAp8tADCAKLz82TwAORbewcnZ5cdNIf4tPPHF5cvb8ePwIkgAD0gIawGBlhohTiEmk-XBEKiLVi8nisLBIJSqWAEBgCFwxAQ5CQaCweCIcDU40m00gsFm4BEi2Wqz6ICAA)

See my [article](https://catchts.com/mutations) about TS mutations

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand where that `LOG` variable is coming from, but here's the rest of it :

```
interface keyValuePair {
    key: string,
    value: string,
}

function toKeyValList<T extends object>(e: T) : keyValuePair[] {
  return Object.entries(e).reduce((acc, val : [string, string]) => {
    acc.push({ key: val[0], value: val[1] });
    return acc;
  }, [] as keyValuePair[]);
}

enum IncidentRecordStatus {
  IN_PROCESS = 'IN_PROCESS',
  CLOSE = 'CLOSE',
}

const list = toKeyValList(IncidentRecordStatus);
```

This would return :

```
[{
  "key": "IN_PROCESS",
  "value": "IN_PROCESS"
}, {
  "key": "CLOSE",
  "value": "CLOSE"
}]
```